# "foo(int* pointer)" vs. "foo(int* &pointer)"

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to learn exactly how pointers **(*)** and references **(&)** work.

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void test1(int* pointer)
{
    int foo = 2;
    pointer = &foo;
}

void test2(int* &pointer)
{
    int foo = 3;
    pointer = &foo;
}

int main()
{
    int aux = 1;
    int* p = &aux;

    test1(p);
    cout << *p << ",";
    test2(p);
    cout << *p << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Which outputs `1,3`

Why does `test1` manage to change the memory location at which **p** is pointing to but `test1` doesn't?

Since `test1` isn't changing **p**, then what is the line `pointer = &foo;` doing on `test1`?

Comment: Both `test1` and `test2` have a bug, they are taking the address of a function-local variable, which falls out of scope, thus they are left with dangling pointers

Comment: @CoryKramer: Actually, `test1` does not create a dangling pointer, because it does not return the pointer to the local variable.

Comment: @CoryKramer What would be the correct way of changing `int* pointer` into a newly created object?

Comment: After `test1()`, `p` is still pointing to `aux` because you passed a copy (by value).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp So in order to modify `p`, I would need to pass a pointer to the pointer?

Comment: Yes, or a reference as you do in `test2()`. (Just keep in mind what @CoryKramer stated about returning a pointer to a local variable.)

Comment: "I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to learn exactly how pointers (*) and references (&) work."  - read a book  ; C++ is not well suited to learn by trial and error

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the suggestion, but reading from multiple pdfs and sources is what actually made me question this, since none of them actually addressed this notation for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference

C++ has two general ways to pass a value to a function - pass-by-value, as in `void foo(int i)`, and pass-by-reference, as in `void foo(int &i)`. Pass-by-value makes a copy of the value that's passed in, whereas pass-by-reference binds a reference to the value that's passed in. As such, a function that uses pass-by-value can't modify the original value, because the function only has a copy, whereas pass-by-reference provides a way to modify the original value through the reference.

In the case of `test1`, what you're doing is passing a value of a pointer type by value. When you call `test1(p)`, it's as if you did this:

```
int foo = 2;
pointer = &foo;
```

As such, `p` is unchanged.

In the case of `test2`, you're passing a value of a pointer type by reference, which does produce a change in `p`. You could actually write the following and it would have the same effect:

```
int *&pointer = p;
int foo = 3;
pointer = &foo;
```

### Undefined behavior

Note that you typically don't want to take the address of a local variable like `foo` and assign it to something outside the function, as you're doing in `test2`. The result of calling `test2(p)` is that `p` points to an object that no longer exists, so any attempt to read from `p` would produce what's called "undefined behavior" - basically, the computer may have reused the memory that had been used to store `foo` during the execution of `test2`, and you could get a very strange value if you try to read from `p`.

In your example results, `*p` is 3, which looks reasonable, but that's just one possibility. The value could also have been 0, -100, or any other `int` value, and different compilers, different platforms, or even different runs of the program on the same machine might give a different answer. By accessing the value of a dead object, the program steps outside the bounds of normal C++ - at that point, all bets are off and pretty much anything could theoretically happen.